# Voximplant Platform 3rd-party dependencies

Tags: voximplant

Can the Voximplant Platform work with 3rd-party libraries? Сan I install 3rd-party npm dependencies into the Voximplant Platform directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with third-party dependencies via API requests ([guide](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/voxengine/api), [reference](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/net)) or WebSockets ([guide](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/voxengine/websocket), [reference](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/websocket)).

You cannot install third-party npm dependencies into the Voximplant Platform directly. You can find more information in the [Limits and restrictions article](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/voxengine/limits).